# Astra Wodpress Theme - Changing the look of Wocommerce Single Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theme-astra

I would like to change some things in Single Product Page.

Does Astra theme has its own single product file somewhere, or I need to modify wocommerce single product files?

Answer (score -2):

You can change the single product page as per your requirement,
But to do that you have to buy Astra pro for this and then you are good to go for design changes of a single product page.
Here is the link to documentation that helps you to change the single product page design:
https://wpastra.com/docs/single-product-woocommerce/